# How to count the number of entries per row in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a number of large data frames for which I need to know the number of elements in each row. For example, if my dataframe df looks like

```
X Y Z A B
Q R S
```

I would want the following output vector:

```
5
3
```

How can I code for this in R?

Comment: That is one strange data.frame. Can you provide a sample of your data in R compatible objects?

Comment: I would be happy to -- but I'm so new at this that I have to ask: what do you mean by "R-compatible objects"?

Comment: You're in luck. There is just the resource you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the non-missing elements (assuming the columns that doesn't have values are `NA`)

```
rowSums(!is.na(df))
```

If the values are blank `""` instead of `NA`, then create the logical matrix with `==` and use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(df != "")
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. You can use `apply`, but should be slower i.e. `apply(!is.na(df), 1, sum)`

Comment: The values are indeed blank, and your rowSums(df != "") solution is exactly what I needed! I had tried using the rowSums function before but didn't know I could indicate blank values with "".

Thank you very much!